# Intersection of two files with uneven columns: print out lines of common columns

Tags: text-processing

I would like to compare two files find common lines between column 1 of each file and print out the full line (multiple columns) of file 1.

file1:

```
a   apple
c   cat
e   eagle
f   fire
g   green   
h   horse   
i   igloo
j   jack
```

and

file2:

```
b
c
d
e
f
```

I would expect the output to be as:

```
c   cat
e   eagle
f   fire
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for coreutils :-)

If the files are already sorted and have the common field in the first column:

```
$ join file1 file2
c cat
e eagle
f fire
```

If your files aren't sorted:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: Also, the `-j 1` is not needed as the default join key is the first column of each file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]++ ; next}; $1 in a' file2 file1
c   cat
e   eagle
f   fire
```

This reads in `file2` (the first filename argument) and stores it in array `a`.  It detects whether it is reading the first file by checking whether `NR` (the total number of input records seen so far) is equal to `FNR` (the input record number of the current input file)

Then it reads `file1` (the second filename argument) and if the first field is in array `a`, it prints the matching input line (in `awk`, the default action on any successful test result, such as `$1 in a`, is to print the input line - so `$1 in a` by itself is equivalent to `$1 in a {print}`).

---

BTW, in many cases, tasks like this can be done with `grep -f file2 file1` but that will match the contents of file2 **anywhere** in file1 - e.g. `c` from file2 would match not only `cat` but also `jack` in file1.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `grep`'s `-f` option with the help of `sed` (as suggested by cas):

```
$ grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file2) file1
c   cat
e   eagle
f   fire
```

Command `sed 's/^/^/' file2` adds a caret `^` to the start of each line in `file2`. We use this output as pattern input file for `grep`'s `-f` option using a process substitution (`<(…)`).

The `grep` command prints those lines in `file1` matching the patterns of the command substitution. We need the `^` character in our patterns to match those lines which are *starting* with the given character.